# How to centralize all IIS-centric data to a shared network drive?

Tags: azure, iis, virtual-machine, replication

I have an azure windows VM with IIS with a shared network drive attached to it. 
Now I add another VM combined with a load balancer, but to prevent having to maintain IIS in 2 VM's, I thought about moving the IIS settings to my shared drive (which is already used for data storage for my webapps).

How can I do this? I have similar issues for windows taskscheduler, is there a way to move these settings to different (shared) locations?

Comment: `a shared network drive` do you mean file share service?  you want to mount it to two VMs, and used for store IIS config files? the two VMs in different location work as backup?

Comment: the IIS config files will be stored on a azure file service (-drive) indeed. The other VM's will work as a replication combined with load balancing for availabilty. Another way is to 'model' my base VM and replicate that (as with azure scale sets), but it seems easier at this point to just store as much OS data in a centralized place to minimize setup for any additional VM

Comment: in 2 locations? do you mean your VMs in different locations?

Comment: The VM's will be in the same region, same Vnet, under the same load balancer. I now see the use of 'locations' in my question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to move these settings to different (shared) locations

Do you mean two VMs use the one configure file? yes, this same as on-prem, we can mount the shared network drive to two VMs, and delegating configuration sections from server-level configuration files to Web.config files in your sites, applications, and virtual or physical directories.

More information about IIS configuration files, please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks for the info :)